# rewrite url using config.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, url-rewrite

I'd created a module and the url for the same is something like:

```
http://magento.korenpub.com/designer/index/index/id/26/value/Joseph%20B.%20Soloveitchik
```

but I need to rewrite the url to

```
http://magento.korenpub.com/author/id/26/value/Joseph%20B.%20Soloveitchik
```

How can it be done with `config.xml`? I'd read this [blog](http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/magento-url-rewrite-using-config-xml-and-regular-expressions/) which describes such, but I'm unable to do it for my module.

**Code from config.xml**

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/$#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/$1]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Comment: What do you mean under "I'm unable to do it for my module"?
Could you please add more description to your problem?

Comment: I'd written this code `<from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/$#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/$1]]></to>` but it redirects to 404

Comment: `http://magento.korenpub.com/designer/index/index/id/26/value/Joseph%20B.%20Soloveitchik` is live and you can check this. I need it to be shorten and replace **designer** with **author**.

Comment: Could you please add your config.xml to the question?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Could you also add your extension's `<routers>` config.xml part?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13677/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd been thinking it in more complicated way but its so simple

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Comment: Works! Magento v1.9.1.  I was confused for the longest because I had from and to values switched. From is the URL you want enter in your browser, and to is the route you want to map to.

Comment: Isn't this the outdated method?

Comment: @hakre: not sure! but it worked for me what I need to be.

Comment: Yeah, I stand corrected. It's not outdated, I just was thinking about overloading or controller via `<routers>`. Nvm & thanks for quick response!