# Changing the frontend URL of an extension

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, extensions

I have downloaded an extension and by default the frontend URL is /faq

A snippet of the config XML looks like

http://pastebin.com/XPjQfbZr

What do I need to do to make the extension work with the frontend URL of /foo/bar/test/faq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a rewrite for this, it might be easier and more flexible in your case than changing the frontend router.

```
<global>
<rewrite>
    <designer_url>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </designer_url>
</rewrite>
```

See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/rewrite-url-using-config-xml) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the frontend name

```
<frontName>test</frontName>
```

Then your url will be /test

Comment: Thats great however I want it to be /foo/bar/test/faq

Is that possible?